# EasyAdminBundle transliterator_transliterate error for file uploads

Tags: symfony4, easyadmin

I have an EasyAdmin form field setup in easy_admin.yaml:

```
- { property: 'imageFile', type: 'file_upload', type_options: { upload_dir: 'public/data/gallery/images/', upload_filename: '[uuid]-[timestamp].[extension]'}}
```

When I try to upload a file I get an error:

```
Attempted to call function "transliterator_transliterate" from namespace "EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Form\Type".
```

If I remove this part - it works fine:

```
upload_filename: '[uuid]-[timestamp].[extension]'
```

What is wrong with this part of the config?

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that it's Symfony's way to say that the function "transliterator_transliterate" doesn't exist. I didn't have the `php-intl` package activated on my server - uncommenting this line `;extension=php_intl.dll` in `php.ini` solved the problem.